# Laravel external(from another domain) api request to check if the user is logged in a server (main server)

Tags: php, laravel, api, request

How can I make a logged-in-check via an external call (external domain) to a main server? Should be a js client-server call.

In other words domain1.com makes a client-server call to the main-domain.com to check if the user is already logged-in in main-domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can:

- Use simply api token authentication on main domain.
- Setup OAuth on main domain.

Comment: The main Domain is an OAuth2.0 and uses JWT

Comment: You need to setup some kind of authentication token on main domain for a user. Domain1 then should have that specific token stored as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is crossdomain request with cookies, this requires that you must specify some header output on the domains, you can find more information @ [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies).

You'll need some kind of handler on the main domain that can start the session, verify that it has the necessary session data that says its logged in and return true/false for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, easiest way is to maintain a flag in your main domain.
So what you need to do is.

1. Add one field in users table, let's say `isLoggedIn`
2. Create an API which return true or false when you make a call from domain1.com
3. Handle data based on the result of the API.

Comment: How can I know which user is making the request so that I can check in the users table?

Comment: Well you will have to pass any common request parameter. For example email id.

Comment: Unfortunately at this point I dont have any user data, since the user is logged out.